# Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an Android app using xamarin on Visual Studio. Target and Compiling from API 26 and API 21 min. My app runs great in debug but crashes before even opening the splash screen on release mode. I get the below error. I have already cleaned, rebuilt and built the app and restarted VS.

```
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175): Process: com.es.responsemaster, PID: 24175
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f060008
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6334)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5923)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5862)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f060008
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourcePackageName(ResourcesImpl.java:248)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(Resources.java:2783)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbz.<init>(Unknown Source)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1758)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1733)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6331)
06-08 16:18:16.494 E/AndroidRuntime(24175):     ... 10 more
```

Any help is much appreciated. I have already spent a few hours trying to google the problem and most of the results are discussing uses of android studio and editing build.gradle. I don't have a build.gradle file. Help please I am lost.

UPDATE:

So after updating Plugins.Firebase, Xamarin.Forms and some clean and rebuilds I can now deploy in release mode with Linking turned off but if I try to set Linking to "Sdk Assemblies Only" I get the following error on build:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void Plugin.FirebasePushNotification.DefaultPushNotificationHandler::OnReceived(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.Object>)' in assembly: 'Plugin.FirebasePushNotification.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat/Builder::.ctor(Android.Content.Context,System.String)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessEntireQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() ResponseMaster.Droid
```

Comment: Also as in attempt to troubleshoot I have set "Linking" to "None" with the same result.

Comment: I will give that a try right now. Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: @SushiHangover I just tried same result after removing app, rebooting device and doing a fresh install. I still get: 
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f060008

Comment: @SushiHangover I am using Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.550146 and the plugin: Plugin.FirebasePushNotification v 2.3.0 and all the Xamarin,Android.Support* in my project are 26.1.0.1

Comment: Xamarin.Andorid version?

Comment: Sorry I am kinda new at xamarin forms, where can I find that?

Comment: Have you checked your dependencies?

Comment: I am kind of new to this. How  would I go about checking that? All the references are showing available and it works in debug so I assume the dependencies are present and valid.